# Help with an $\epsilon$, $\delta$ proof

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, epsilon-delta

For all $(x,y) \in \mathbf{R}^{2}$ I am trying to find a $\delta > 0$ such that
$$\sqrt{(x_{1} -x_{2})^{2} + (y_{1} - y_{2})} < \delta \Rightarrow \left|x_{1} - x_{2}\right| + \left|y_{1}-y_{2}\right| < \epsilon$$
So far I have that
\begin{align*}
  & \left|x_{1} - x_{2}\right| + \left|y_{1}-y_{2}\right| < \epsilon\\
  \Rightarrow & \left|x_{1} - x_{2}\right|^{2} + 2 \left|x_{1} - x_{2}\right| \left|y_{1}-y_{2}\right|+ \left|y_{1} - y_{2}\right|^{2} < \epsilon^{2}\\
  \Rightarrow & \left|x_{1} - x_{2}\right|^{2} + \left|y_{1} - y_{2}\right|^{2} < \epsilon^{2} - 2 \left|x_{1} - x_{2}\right| \left|y_{1}-y_{2}\right|\\
  \Rightarrow & \left(x_{1} - x_{2}\right)^{2} + \left(y_{1} - y_{2}\right)^{2} < \epsilon^{2} - 2 \left|x_{1} - x_{2}\right| \left|y_{1}-y_{2}\right|\\
  \Rightarrow & \sqrt{\left(x_{1} - x_{2}\right)^{2} + \left(y_{1} - y_{2}\right)^{2}} < \sqrt{\epsilon^{2} - 2 \left|x_{1} - x_{2}\right| \left|y_{1}-y_{2}\right|}\\
\end{align*}
So if I let $\delta = \sqrt{\epsilon^{2} - 2 \left|x_{1} - x_{2}\right| \left|y_{1}-y_{2}\right|}$ I can reverse the above to show what I want. The problem
is that I need to show that $\epsilon^{2} - 2 \left|x_{1} - x_{2}\right| \left|y_{1}-y_{2}\right| > 0$ and I am having trouble seeing how to do that or finding
a bound for $2 \left|x_{1} - x_{2}\right| \left|y_{1}-y_{2}\right|$.

Comment: IMO it's easier to see what to do here if you think geometrically. Consider $(x_2,y_2) = (0,0)$ then it says $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} < \delta \implies |x| + |y| < \epsilon$.  The first inequality says that $(x,y)$ has to be contained within a circle of radius $\delta$ of the origin. From this it's not too hard to see that $|x| + |y| < 2\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2 + (y_1-y_2)^2} < \delta$ implies that both $|x_1-x_2|$ and $|y_1-y_2|$ are less than $\delta$.

This implies that $|x_1-x_2|+|y_1-y_2| < 2\delta$.

So, you can choose $\delta= \epsilon/2$

Comment: $|x_1 - x_2|$ and $|y_1 - y_2|$ are less than $\delta$, not necessarily less than $\sqrt{\delta}$, I think.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I will correct it.